# Why do I see multiple Jars in the Servers tab in RAD?

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-rad

I am trying to publish my EAR project in IBM WebSphere 8.5 but I see multiple copies of a few jars in the servers tab under my EAR project. This does not look right to me. I ask because I am having some problems(deploying issues) in my workspace after reorganizing jars and I hope this is not the cause. A little advice in this regard would be certainly helpful for me to understand what is really going on. Thanks!

[image]

***PS:*** The two files that I could not show are My EAR Project followed by a Java Project.

***Update:*** I have 7 projects in total including EAR, Web, EJB Projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jars mysteriously disappeared when I switched to a new 64-bit machine and deployed the same project. Most probably the Websphere 8.5 installation might have gotten corrupted on the older 32-bit one. Even creating new server profiles didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are adding them more than once, for instance, in the java project and the EAR project.  You need to sort out where the jar references need to be resolved and only specify them in that project and make sure the resulting dependencies all map out.

Comment: Yes, I have added these files both in my EAR and Web Projects. But I have added in total 20 Jars which are common, to both these projects and only these jars are shown duplicated on the servers tab. How is that possible? In that case I should see 20 duplicate Jars here. Can you please explain that?